# Datatable - aaSorting not working in $.extend.defaults

Tags: jquery, datatable

I use dataTable in my application, and by default, the first column is sorted.. So I took a look on the documentation, and I find the famous "aaSorting: []" to disable the default sorting.

But ! I wanted to use the extended params, cause I don't want to write each time this params :

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
"oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
    "sSearch": "Chercher dans le tableau : ",
    "sInfo": "_START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_ lignes"
},
"iDisplayLength": 25,
"bLengthChange" : 0,
"aaSorting" : []
});
```

And it doesn't work ! Please look this fiddle, I think it is impossible to do this... :http://jsfiddle.net/KDPY3/

If someone have an idea... Thanks !

Comment: do u want to disable sorting?? then set `"aaSorting" : false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a satisfactory explanation, but removing the "deep copy" part works :

```
$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, { "aaSorting": [] } );
```

or

```
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.aaSorting = [];
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDPY3/3/)

This may be a starting point : Datatable has a custom internal [`_fnExtend`](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/4c4bfb04b88d1f2bf304940157b651d1e936cb79/media/src/core/core.support.js#L168) function, which deep copies objects, not arrays.

I haven't tracked how the options are manipulated during the initialisation, though.

Comment: Allright ! Thanks a lot, it works. Thanks for your explanation, I was curious to know about this problem.